# Where can I find QEMU (TCG)'s / LLVM IR operational semantics?

Tags: llvm, qemu, intermediate-language

Is anyone aware pf any public QEMU's TCG operational semantics description?
I rather found something about LLVM, but I'm not sure if these two are quite similar? especially that TCGs use sometimes custom helper functions rather than micro-ops.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks.
Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

tcg/README in the QEMU sources is the documentation for the various TCG ops. Note that the exact set and semantics of TCG ops are purely an internal implementation detail of QEMU -- they can and do change (mostly adding new ops, but occasionally clarifying or changing existing ones).

There's no relationship between LLVM IR and QEMU TCG, except that both are instances of the very common compiler design pattern of "use an architecture-agnostic intermediate representation".